# Oracle Object Type Constructor Called Multiple Times

Tags: oracle

I have an object type with a custom constructor. In SQL, when I reference the attributes the constructor is called multiple times.

- Why is the constructor called multiple times?
- How do I stop it?

My current work around is to reference the attributes and use the /*+ materialize */ hint.

---

**Problem Setup**

```sql
create or replace type Foo as object
(
  Bar1 NUMBER,
  Bar2 NUMBER,
  Bar3 NUMBER,

  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Foo(p_Bar1 NUMBER, p_Bar2 NUMBER, p_Bar3 NUMBER)
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
    DETERMINISTIC
)

create or replace type body Foo is

  -- Member procedures and functions
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Foo(p_Bar1 NUMBER, p_Bar2 NUMBER, p_Bar3 NUMBER)
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
    DETERMINISTIC
  AS
  BEGIN
    SELF.Bar1 := p_Bar1;
    SELF.Bar2 := p_Bar2;
    SELF.Bar3 := p_Bar3;
    dbms_output.put_line('Foo Constructor Called');
    RETURN;
  END;

end;
```

**Problem**

```sql
-- Constructor is called 6 times! 
-- Once for each column and once for each predicate in the where clause.
SELECT x.f.bar1 AS bar1, x.f.bar2 AS bar2, x.f.bar3 AS bar3, f
FROM (
  SELECT foo(p_Bar1 => 1, p_Bar2 => 2, p_Bar3 => 3) f
  FROM dual d
) x
WHERE x.f.bar1 = x.f.bar1 AND x.f.bar2 = x.f.bar2
```

---

**Workaround**

```sql
-- Work Around
-- Constructor is called 3 times
-- Once for each column in the inline view. 
-- Note, I removed column f (the object type) because it's not compatible with the materialize hint.
WITH y AS (
  SELECT /*+ materialize */ x.f.bar1 AS bar1, x.f.bar2 AS bar2, x.f.bar3 AS bar3
  FROM (
    SELECT foo(p_Bar1 => 1, p_Bar2 => 2, p_Bar3 => 3) f
    FROM dual d
  ) x
)
SELECT y.bar1, y.bar2, y.bar3
FROM y
WHERE y.bar1 = y.bar1 AND y.bar2 = y.bar2
```

Comment: How many rows do you select with that statement? May I guess _3_ ?

Comment: Each select statements produce 1 row. While DBMS_Output.Put_line in the constructor writes 6 times for the "Problem" and 3 times for the "Workaround".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of a collection type combined with the table operator.

```sql
create or replace type FooTable as table of Foo;  

SELECT x.bar1 AS bar1, x.bar2 AS bar2, x.bar3 AS bar3, value(x) f   
    FROM table(FooTable(   
      foo(p_Bar1 => 1, p_Bar2 => 2, p_Bar3 => 3)   
    )) x   
    WHERE x.bar1 = x.bar1 AND x.bar2 = x.bar2  
;  

BAR1 BAR2 BAR2 F  
1    2    3    (1, 2, 3)  

Foo Constructor Called
```

Credit goes to [gaverill](https://community.oracle.com/people/gaverill) on the Oracle Forums.

[Oracle Object Type Constructor Called Multiple Times](https://community.oracle.com/message/12995247#12995247)